Mutual information when sampling a random variable multiple times
Let $X$ be a random variable. For a fixed (known) preparation of $X$, suppose I have a protocol that generates a second random variable, $Y$, in a way that indirectly depends on $X$. Ultimately the goal is to estimate $X$ via $Y$; you may think of $Y$ as a measured quantity (say, in an experiment) and of $X$ as the actual value of the property we would like to measure.
For such a protocol, we can compute $I \left( X; Y \right)$, which for our purposes is the performance of the protocol.
Now, suppose I can sample $Y$ multiple times for the same preparation of $X$. How do I model - and calculate - the mutual information of $X$ with $n$ samples of $Y$?
